# Is there an "easy" way of animating scatterplots in Python?

Tags: animation, optimization, scatter-plot

I've been looking at a couple of discussions on this today but I dont know how to implement the suggested solutions to my problem. Hopefully someone can give me a working example or some hint.

So, in the current code I basically start with the vertices of a triangle and plot a starting point at coordinates (2,2). In the for loop I generate a random number between 1 and 6 and depending on what that number is, the starting point moves half way to one of the vertices, which corresponds to plotting a new point. The process is then iterated with that new point n=5 times (in the code below)

I would like to see the graph/plot as the new points are getting plotted for some number of iterations n, to see what picture emerges. How can I do this? Is there some easy approach?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random as r



x = [0, 6, 3]
y = [0, 0, 8]

x0 = x[0]
y0 = y[0]
x1 = x[1]
y1 = y[1]
x2 = x[2]
y2 = y[2]

pt = [2,2]
plt.scatter(pt[0], pt[1], color='blue')
plt.scatter(x,y,color='red')

for i in range(1,5):

  randNum = r.randint(1,6)

  if randNum == 1 or randNum == 2:
      plt.scatter((pt[0]+x0)/2,(pt[1]+y0)/2,color='black')
      pt = [(pt[0]+x0)/2,(pt[1]+y0)/2]

  elif randNum == 3 or randNum == 4:
      plt.scatter((pt[0]+x1)/2,(pt[1]+y1)/2,color='black')
      pt = [(pt[0]+x1)/2,(pt[1]+y1)/2]

  elif randNum == 5 or randNum == 6:
      plt.scatter((pt[0]+x2)/2,(pt[1]+y2)/2,color='black')
      pt = [(pt[0]+x2)/2,(pt[1]+y2)/2]



plt.show()
```